# 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem' does not contain a definition for

Tags: c#, sharepoint

> 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem' does not contain a definition for
>   'Image' and no extension method 'Image' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem' could be found

```
string[] fields = new string[] { "Title", "Image", "Description", "Content" };

SPListItemCollection collection = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.Lists["FOO"].GetItems(fields);

Response.Write(collection[0].Image);
```

but `Response.Write(collection[0].Title);` works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Title` is a member defined on the `SPListItem` class. Every List will have a field called Title, unless you go through laborious steps to remove it, so it's there on the base object.

To get custom properties / fields, you want to use something like:

```
Response.Write(collection[0]["Image"]);
```

Comment: Item and GetItem both didn't work. 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem' does not contain a definition for 'GetItem' and no extension method 'GetItem' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem' could be found

Comment: Yes, sorry, `GetItem` was a typo on my part.

Comment: weird. try just `collection[0]["Image"]` ?